# Как обновить поле с текстом запроса в DataSource?

Tags: android, recyclerview, mvvm, livedata, paging

Пытаюсь реализовать следующую задачу. Есть два фрагмента: первый фрагмент отображает полученные с сервера результаты запроса (recyclerView), второй состоит из поля для запроса и кнопки "Искать". Как мне обновлять значение запроса в DataSource, когда пользователь нажимает кнопку искать? То есть, мне нужно сделать новый запрос на сервер и обновить данные в recyclerView. Запрос на сервер реализован в DataSource. Там же лежит и поле, которое представляет текущий запрос. Его и нужно обновить значением из EditText, но не знаю как это реализовать. Вот мой код: https://github.com/RafalskyCodit/retrofitAndPagingLibrary
Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Я вас правильно понял - вы хотите реализовать поиск для кнопки "Искать" по введенной информации в поле поиска ?

Comment: Да. Вот я использую апи сайта с изображениями. Ввел в поле "Цветы", нажал на кнопку, получил изображения с цветами. Вернулся на предыдущий фрагмент, ввел другой запрос, к примеру "Кошки", получил ресуклвью с изображениями кошек. Вот эту банальную задачу я и хочу реализовать. Только хочу все это сделать именно на mvvm с помощью Retrofit + PagingLibrary.

Comment: Я думаю стоит начать с этого: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide (если всё пойдёт хорошо, то где-то на хабре или ещё где появится на рус.), и прочитать весь цыкл (хотя бы выборочно): https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/529-urok-5-room-osnovy.html. Но если у вас опыта не много, то стоит задуматься над тем что бы это хоть как-то заработало, а потом отрефакторите.